# How to authenticate using OpenID in Tornado?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, tornado, openid, openid-connect

I'm using Tornado web server for a simple web application, and want to authenticate the user using OpenID. I'm new to Tornado, and I managed to work it using Node.js' Passport package (was testing on Node.js first), which I was able to get the `id_token` in the callback.

I'm using `OAuth2Mixin` from `tornado.auth` to authorize the access using user credential grant, then on the redirect, I'm getting the from `code` get param. I don't know how to continue from there :D

```py
from tornado.auth import OpenIdMixin, OAuth2Mixin
from .base import BaseHandler

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler, OAuth2Mixin, OpenIdMixin):
  def get(self):
    self._OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_URL = 'https://authserver.io/uas/oauth2/authorization'
    self._OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'https://authserver.io/uas/oauth2/token'
    self.authorize_redirect(
      redirect_uri='http://localhost:3001/success-login',
      client_id='abcd',
      client_secret='1234',
    )
```

Then on the other handler.

```py
from tornado.auth import OpenIdMixin, OAuth2Mixin
import tornado.httpclient
from .base import BaseHandler

class SuccessLoginHandler(BaseHandler, OpenIdMixin, OAuth2Mixin):
  async def get(self):
    code = self.get_argument('code', None)
    if code is not None:
      return self.write(code)

    self.write('no code')
```

I would expect the `id_token` back; which is a JWT. I can decode it and get the data needed.

**UPDATE:**
In case the configurations are needed.

```
{"issuer":"https://authserver.io/uas","authorization_endpoint":"https://authserver.io/uas/oauth2/authorization","token_endpoint":"https://authserver.io/uas/oauth2/token","userinfo_endpoint":"https://authserver.io/uas/oauth2/userinfo","jwks_uri":"https://authserver.io/uas/oauth2/metadata.jwks","tokeninfo_endpoint":"https://authserver.io/uas/oauth2/introspection","introspection_endpoint":"https://authserver.io/uas/oauth2/introspection","revocation_endpoint":"https://authserver.io/uas/oauth2/revocation","response_types_supported":["code"],"grant_types_supported":["authorization_code","password","refresh_token","urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer","http://globalsign.com/iam/sso/oauth2/grant-type/sms-mt-otp","http://globalsign.com/iam/sso/oauth2/grant-type/smtp-otp"],"subject_types_supported":["public"],"request_object_signing_alg_values_supported":["RS256","HS256"],"request_object_encryption_alg_values_supported":["RSA-OAEP","RSA1_5","A128KW"],"request_object_encryption_enc_values_supported":["A128GCM","A128CBC-HS256"],"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":["RS256","HS256"],"id_token_encryption_alg_values_supported":["RSA-OAEP","RSA1_5","A128KW"],"id_token_encryption_enc_values_supported":["A128GCM","A128CBC-HS256"],"userinfo_signing_alg_values_supported":["RS256","HS256"],"userinfo_encryption_alg_values_supported":["RSA-OAEP","RSA1_5","A128KW"],"userinfo_encryption_enc_values_supported":["A128GCM","A128CBC-HS256"],"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["client_secret_post","client_secret_basic","client_secret_jwt","private_key_jwt"],"token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported":["RS256","HS256"],"introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["client_secret_post","client_secret_basic","client_secret_jwt","private_key_jwt"],"introspection_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported":["RS256","HS256"],"revocation_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["client_secret_post","client_secret_basic","client_secret_jwt","private_key_jwt"],"revocation_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported":["RS256","HS256"],"scopes_supported":["openid","userinfo"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Tornado's `httpclient` to send the requests to the OpenID server.

```py
import base64
import urllib.parse
import json
import tornado.httpclient

from .base import BaseHandler
from settings import OID_AUTH_API, OID_REDIRECT_URI, OID_CLIENT_ID, OID_CLIENT_PASSWORD
from lib import logger

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    _redirect_uri = urllib.parse.quote(OID_REDIRECT_URI, safe='')
    _scope = 'openid+profile+email'
    _response_type = 'code'
    _http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

    async def get(self):
        try:
            code = self.get_argument('code', None)

            if (code is None):
                self.redirect('%s/authorization?client_id=%s&scope=%s&response_type=%s&redirect_uri=%s' % (
                    OID_AUTH_API, OID_CLIENT_ID, self._scope, self._response_type, self._redirect_uri), self.request.uri)
                return

            # exchange the authorization code with the access token
            grant_type = 'authorization_code'
            redirect_uri = self._redirect_uri
            authorization_header = '%s:%s' % (
                OID_CLIENT_ID, OID_CLIENT_PASSWORD)
            authorization_header_encoded = base64.b64encode(
                authorization_header.encode('UTF-8')).decode('UTF-8')
            url = '%s/token?grant_type=%s&code=%s&redirect_uri=%s' % (
                OID_AUTH_API, grant_type, code, redirect_uri)
            token_exchange_response = await self._http_client.fetch(
                url,
                method='POST',
                headers={
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % authorization_header_encoded,
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
                body='')

            token_exchange_response_body_dict = json.loads(
                token_exchange_response.body)

            access_token = token_exchange_response_body_dict.get(
                'access_token')

            self.send_response({
                'access_token': access_token
            })
        except tornado.httpclient.HTTPClientError as error:
            logger.log_error(error.response.body.decode('UTF-8'))

            self.send_response({
                'success': False,
                'message': 'Error occurred while trying to obtain the access token'
            }, 500)
        except Exception as error:
            logger.log_error_with_traceback(error)
            self.send_response({
                'success': False,
                'message': 'Internal server error. Please try again later.'
            }, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call [`get_authenticated_user`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/auth.html#tornado.auth.OAuthMixin.get_authenticated_user) from `SuccessLoginHandler` to get the access token.

But, I'd rather write everything in a single handler to keep code shorter and non repetitive. You can rewrite `LoginHandler` like this:

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler, OAuth2Mixin, OpenIdMixin):

    _OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_URL = 'https://authserver.io/uas/oauth2/authorization'
    _OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'https://authserver.io/uas/oauth2/token'

    async def get(self):
        redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:3001/login'

        code = self.get_argument('code', None)

        if code:
            # if there's `code`, get access token
            user = await self.get_authenticated_user()

            # the `user` variable now contains the returned data
            # from the oauth server.
            # you'll probably want to `set_secure_cookie`
            # or do something else to save the user

            # then redirect the user to some page
            self.redirect("/") # redirects to home page
            return 

        else:
            # otherwise get authorization `code`       
            self.authorize_redirect(
                redirect_uri=redirec_uri,
                client_id='abcd',
                client_secret='1234',
            )
```

Comment: It's complaining about the number of the argument passed to the `get_authenticated_user`. 
```TypeError: get_authenticated_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'redirect_uri'```

Comment: Here is the method definition

`async def get_authenticated_user(
        self, http_client: httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient = None
    )`

Comment: @Qvikie Ah! Sorry about that. Just call `get_authenticated_user` without any arguments.

Comment: @Qvikie Also, if the `code` is required for getting the access token, you may have to override `get_authenticated_user` and make the HTTP request manually, as done in [`GoogleOAuth2Mixin`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/auth.html#GoogleOAuth2Mixin.get_authenticated_user) class.

Comment: Didn't work! I got some other errors. I had to implement this manually by sending requests using the `tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()`.